# How to change / assign BGCOLOR to a field/cell/row/column in a freeform query

Tags: colors, progress-4gl, openedge

I am using a freeform query that will populate the temp table fields. i can adjust the width fine but i cant assign a color to the field/cell/row/column. How do you assign color ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer. I also did a workaround and ask a coworker and found a different answer.

under DISPLAY trigger of freeform query.

```
tt-table COLUMN-FGCOLOR 15 COLUMN-BGCOLOR 3.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a "row display trigger" to go with your browse widget.  Something like:

```
on row-display of f anywhere do:

  if "{&window-system}" = "tty" then
    columnHandle:dcolor  = getColorNum( "red" ).
   else
    columnHandle:fgcolor = getColorNum( "red" ).

  return.

end.
```

Something like this might be handy for getting the columnHandle:

```
function getBrowseColumnByName returns handle ( z as handle, n as character ):

  define variable c as handle no-undo.

  c = z:first-column.

  do while valid-handle( c ):
    if c:name = n then
      leave.
     else
      c = c:next-column.
  end.

  return c.

end.
```